# Delete till first close bracket starting from specific keyword

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a variable which contains:

```
var="I am in digital india today i will go home))) and have a dinner"
```

I want to delete from the word `today` up to and including the next right parenthesis. The output should be:

```
I am in digital india )) and have a dinner
```

I tried doing with sed, but it doesn't work:

```
$ echo $var | sed 's/today.*)//'
I am in digital india and have a dinner
```

There could be anywhere from 1-4 close brackets. I need to delete the first one and leave the rest alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.*` is greedy. It will match as much input as possible, meaning `)` will match the last parenthesis instead of the first one. In most other regex engines you could turn off greediness by writing `.*?`. Sed doesn't support that, so instead you can change `.` to `[^)]` to prevent it from matching any parentheses.

```
echo $var | sed 's/today[^)]*)//'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bash, leverage `extglob`. To check if `extglob` is on, command `shopt extglob` and if it's off command `shopt -s extglob`. Then:

```
$ echo "${var/today*([!\)])\)}"
I am in digital india )) and have a dinner
```

Explained:

- `${var/foo/bar}` replaces (first occurance of) `foo` with `bar` in variable `$var`
- `*(PATTERN)` matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
- `*([!\)])\)` matches zero on more occurrences of "*not* ) *followed by a* )"

Comment: Updated to match the challenges of rapidly changing requirements of the modern world!

Answer (score -1):

It works... But I don't know if you want this way...

```
echo $var | sed 's/today.*.e)//'

echo $var | sed 's/today.*)/)/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tomonso Ejang this will work for generic situation. But in my case i have a file in which each line has minimun one close bracker and max three or four close bracket so that is the reason i want to delete till first bracket and rest bracket will be there.